# Save file MD5 hash to file metadata

Tags: powershell, metadata, md5

I have a large number of XML based data files with complex contents. Currently I am validating the contents at every use, and that is slow. I started thinking I could have a utility to validate the XML, then get an MD5 hash of the file and save it to the file meta data. Then, at use I can compare saved hash with current hash and only validate those files that are different.
At least, I can do a performance comparison and see if that will actually be any faster.
That said, I am not finding any way to add a custom Hash property to the file meta data. And I wonder if there is a better way to do this?
For some other XML files I am using code signing, but those are program resource XML files that I provide. These other XML files are modified by the customer for use, so I can't use code signing.
I also could include a text file that lists the XML files and their associated hashes, but storing the hash in the file seems a more elegant solution. It just seems like Windows is less than forthcoming with the custom metadata options. At least local files. Of course there is all sorts of metadata options when files are on SharePoint, or AWS S3, etc. And indeed, I need to be able to hash files and save that as metadata on the file, and have it survive a round trip through a cloud repository too, since that is the solution I am looking at for solving the Work From Home problem. A company would create and validate their XML files, then upload them to an S3 bucket, then code on the user machine would download and use them.

Am I on the right track, or is this a dead end? And if so, might a self-signed certificate solve the issue? Create your certificate and share the public key with users. Then sign your XML with it. That feels... not ideal.

Comment: If it's on an NTFS drive, maybe look at [alternate data stream](https://davidhamann.de/2019/02/23/hidden-in-plain-sight-alternate-data-streams/)?

Comment: @stargeek I think that's exactly what I was looking for. A bit kludgy in PowerShell, but I think I can make it work. Now to do some performance comparisons to make sure it's WORTH making it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that this approach was indeed a dead end, due to the fact that I can't ensure that files will always be hosted on an NTFS formatted drive. Especially in smaller firms a NAS is a common location, and with Work from Home becoming a thing, so is a local external FAT32 formatted drive.
The solution is to prevalidate the XML, get a hash of the XML as a string, and then add that hash to the root node at an attribute. The XML load code can then pass loaded XML to a method that compares the value of that hash to a rehash of the same XML as a string, with the attribute removed. Net result, a universally applicable way to verify if the XML is changed since prevalidation. Which was really the goal.